# What diffrence bitween these two mysql operators

Tags: mysql

Can any one tell me What diffrence bitween these two mysql operators :-

<=> and =

Both are getting same results. Are they same in use.

```
select s.dwt,s.shipnam from tbl_ship s
where s.dwt >= 1 and s.deleted = 'N'
and s.dwt = 11000
group by s.co_cod
```

and

```
select s.dwt,s.shipnam from tbl_ship s
where s.dwt >= 1 and s.deleted = 'N'
and s.dwt <=> 11000
group by s.co_cod
```

Thanks.

Comment: Never seen that operator before.  I'd guess that it's simply a union of the <, =, and > operators, i.e. as long as your comparison value isn't null it will be true.  You probably have the same results because the only records that match s.dwt=11000 happen to be the only records that match s.dwt>=1 and s.deleted='n'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<=>` is [NULL-safe equal to operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Answer (score 5):

It is null safe equal to operator :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

From mysql documentation :

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

> <=>   [NULL-safe equal to operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

That's why. You probably wanted to use `<>` or `!=` to test for inequality.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to